# Telescope back button state

Tags: javascript, meteor, state, telescope

Checking Telescope, and it looks pretty great, but...

Is the back button broken when using search?  After entering a search term, if you click on a thread and then hit the browser's back button, Telescope displays the correct search url, but there are no search results.  This makes using search extremely tedious as you have to keep retyping in your search term if you are trying to find something.

I find it hard to believe that the project is far along as it is with such a basic problem that makes it practically unusable.  The project's own forum and demo page suffer from this issue:

http://demo2.telescopeapp.org/

http://meta.telescopeapp.org/

I started looking into the routing and state, but I figured before I move forward, maybe I'm missing something that fixes this easily and I'm just looking in the wrong place.  Thanks

Comment: Well, this is obviously a bug so I'm not sure how you expect someone to answer your "question". Instead of feigning mock indignation over a relatively minor problem, you could've taken the same 2 minutes to file an issue on GitHub.

Comment: Sincerely sorry, I'm new to this.  Please reread my post with the context that I'm an idiot.  The project looked so good that I didn't really think I could have found a bug, but figured it was something that I was screwing up!  Even when I found it on the demo sites, I still doubted it could be a bug, but maybe my browser or something. I will sign up for Github and figure out how to file a issue.

Comment: I was a bit rough with my comment so I apologize as well! The "practically unusable" part ticked me off a bit ;) You can file an issue here: http://github.com/TelescopeJS/Telescope/issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug. I guess it may be considered minor, but as I was searching for the solution in the project's site, it made it really frustrating to use!